# .NET, EF6 - disable recursive validating

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, validation, modelstate

I stuck at validating problem.

I use ModelState to validate models coming from post requests. Here are my models:

MatchGroup model

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "MatchGroupId", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.MatchGroupResources))]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]        
    public Guid MatchGroupId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResources))]
    [Display(Name = "MatchGroupName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.MatchGroupResources))]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResources))]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResources))]
    public string MatchGroupName { get; set; }

    // foreign key
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

CategoryModel

```
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "CategoryId", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.CategoryResources))]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResources))]
    [Display(Name = "CategoryName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.CategoryResources))]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResources))]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.GeneralResources))]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
```

As you can see there is strong validation on "Name" fields. It works correctly for direct objects, but when I try to put an MatchGroup object into a database, Controller throws me ModelState validation error "Category Name" is required.

My request (POST) looks like this:
        Key: Value

```
    MatchGroupName: MatchGroup 4
    Category.CategoryId: 5B8D3AC8-8C97-4BCB-AC1A-1D61BDDADEEF
```

I am doing that like that because lately I am using line below to attach existing object:

```
    context.Category.Attach(model.Category);
```

When I turn off my lines it's ok, but with them I can not proceed:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return ResultModelsHelper<MatchGroup>.GetModelStateResponse(ModelState);
    }
```

Am I missing something? How can I disable validating this Category object which is foreign object? Maybe I get data from POST wrong and I should pass it in other model variable(s)?

Fastest thing I found at stackoverflow is to add line before checking IsValid, but I don't know if it is a good idea:

```
    ModelState.Remove("model.Category.CategoryName");
```

Comment: That, or give `MatchGroup` a `CategoryId` property.

Comment: I tried that too. When I am adding Guid CategoryId into MatchGroup model and fill this by value, it gives me error about empty CategoryName in Category object anyway, even if i do not mark it as required.

Comment: Even if you don't set a `Category` object? The idea is to set `CategoryId` instead of `Category`.

Comment: Hmm, I did it yesterday and didn't work. Now I did the same and it's working. Maybe I had [Required] on Category by mistake.

Comment: Another problem, when updating Entity:

        `matchGroup.MatchGroupName = model.MatchGroupName;
        matchGroup.Category = context.Category.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == model.CategoryId);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();`

It throws me error that field 'CategoryId' I've just added is empty although I marked it as `[NotMapped]`. Adding `modelBuilder.Entity<MatchGroup>()
                .Ignore(e => e.CategoryId)` also didn't help

Comment: It should be a mapped property.